# Multi Ordering 4 SQL columns with a single query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

Environment: MySQL 5.6

SqlTable name = CategoryTable

Sql Columns

- CATEGORY_ID (INT)
- CATEGORY_NAME (VARCHAR)
- LEVEL (INT)
- MOTHER_CATEGORY (INT)

I've tried with

```
SELECT
    CATEGORY_ID, CATEGORY_NAME , LEVEL , MOTHER_CATEGORY
FROM
    CategoryTable
```

But I don't know how to use the ORDER BY in order to get that result.

So the first line here are the columns, and from the second lines, there start the table content:

```
CATEGORY_ID         CATEGORY_NAME            LEVEL     MOTHER_CATEGORY
     1              MainCategory               0               0
     2              -SubCategory1              1               1
     3              --SubCategory2             2               2
     4              ---SubCategory3            3               3
     5              2Nd_Main_Category          0               0
     6              -SubCategory1              1               5
     7              --SubCategory2             2               6
     8              ---SubCategory3            3               7
```

is there a way to achieve something like this with a mysql query?

Comment: You should give us the full data model. I'm inferring that each category is a member of a parent category, and so each row has a column saying which category is the parent. Your 'question' is missing all those details.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Most likely the answer is "yes", but it's unclear to me how the source data looks like.

Comment: Sorry for that, but yes is like you said. I've tried selecting all the 4 tables and trying to ordering by two or more of that but was unable to achieve something like that as result

Comment: The first line are the headers column, the other lines are the table data, I don't know how to order them like I posted once selecting all 4 columns from the MainTable

Comment: Please read the first link I gave, edit your question, and add the missing details. Comments aren't the place to describe what is missing from an example dataset. [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: It's messy in MySQL 5.6, so, can you move to MySQL 8, which you should really do anyway? Or, if you can't, is there a known maximum level?

Comment: MySQL 5.x is reaching end of life in 15 months from now. Maybe you should consider upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't very clear in what you are trying to achieve. I'll take a guess that you want to order using a multi-level parent child structure. there are some very complicated ways of handling such a feat within mysql 5.6, a DB that's not really ideal for such a structure, but I have come up with something simple myself that I use in my own apps. you create a special ordering field that creates a path of zero filled ids for each record.

```
ordering_path_field
/
/0000000001/
/
/0000000001/0000000002
/0000000003
/0000000003/0000000005
/0000000003/0000000005/0000000006
```

etc

so each record contains a path of each parent up to the root, using zero filled ids. then you can just sort by this field to get them in proper order. the drawbacks being that you'll have to set a max number of levels allowed, so that the ordering fields doesn't overflow, and also, moving a record to a new parent if ever needed would be a big pain.

Comment: They're not complicated in MySQL8, only in legacy MySQL5.x. As such, it's worth noting what version you're answering for.  You should also describe the overhead of making changes to the tree structure, as moving one node now entails recursively modifying multiple nodes.

Comment: To the op; this is a denormalised pattern. Research it thoroughly before using it. It is not free and not normally recommended in dynamic environments.